# Why is Hydra classified under Hydrozoa when it has neither a planula larva, nor a medusoid form?

Tags: taxonomy, classification

If the general basis of classification of cnidarians is with respect to the body form - medusoid or polypoid, or in the incidence of metagenesis (as is common in hydrozoa), both, then, on what basis is *Hydra* placed in class Hydrozoa?

Comment: I'd say modern taxonomy doesn't (or at least tries not to?) classify things based on how they appear, but based on how related they are.

Comment: Probably relevant: [Nawrocki et al. 2013. *Phylogenetic placement of Hydra and relationships within Aplanulata (Cnidaria: Hydrozoa)*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23280366)